# Running as user 'root' is a security risk, aborting

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, odoo, erp

I was following this link:

http://www.mindissoftware.com/2014/09/11/Run-Odoo-in-PyCharm-Ubuntu/

I changed the openerp-server.conf file and run the Database located at another machine using host address.

When I run the odoo in Pycharm it throws the error as

> Running as user 'root' is a security risk, aborting.

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be trying to run Odoo with the `root` account: either you logged in as `root`or you are running PyCharm/Odoo with `sudo`.

Comment: You should accept an answer, or add an answer with your solution, otherwise it's not helpful for other people with the same problem.

Comment: I followed this link and resolved my issue. [http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2014/09/how-to-install-openerp-odoo-8-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/]

Comment: The link is broken now :(

Answer (score 0):

## SnippetBucket Expert for Odoo

```
Running as user 'root' is a security risk, aborting.
```

Odoo rules:
1. Odoo can't run with root user, Its because of good govern of ERP Security
2. Odoo - Postgresql, You should not use "postgres" user to run odoo, instead create superuser of postgresql and connect it.

For pycharm, make sure you not run pycharm with root or pycharm don't operate terminal under root. Desktop specific stuff.

Its better to create desktop user, with same name create postgresql super user.
than with newly created desktop user use pycharm. make better to work with odoo.

## G-Edit editor and plugins are my favoite editor, keep less memory and works faster. G-Edit Odoo Snippets gives faster to work.

Thanks

SnippetBucket.com